# How many strongholds per world can there be in minecraft PC edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know how many strongholds there can be per world (as of now) in minecraft PC edition. The last answer I saw was 3, but I think it has changed and want to know if it has changed and if so, what it has changed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed on the [official Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold), there is a maximum of 128 strongholds that can be generated on the PC edition. The console edition can only generate up to 3.